Mathematica 13.1 - New Cell Options
I have been using Mathematica for many years now and never encountered anything like that. My version is 13.1.
In one of my notebooks, I must have clicked some shortcut by mistake, and now the new cell option is always "date".
I have tried going to the "option inspector" and changing DefaultNewCellStyle, but that doesn't do anything.

Even more strange, when starting a new cell by right-clicking the notebook and choosing "insert new cell" the option for "input" no longer appears.

This only happened in this one notebook, the others are ok. I can always copy all the calculations to a new notebook, but that would be annoying.
Does anyone have any idea what is happening?
Thank you.
